# How do I run a keyboard program in the background?

Tags: c++, python, input, keyboard, background-process

I want to make a program where when you press a keyboard key it plays the next sound in a list of sounds (preferably using C++ or python), but I want this to work in any program (Microsoft Word etc.) and just be running in the background. I have no idea how to do this or even where to look.

Also, if anyone knows a good link for learning how to make a program read midi files, that would be nice too.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search for Keyboard Hooks.

Most systems provide a away for you to ask to see any events that go by, either all events, or a subset (keyboard/mouse/etc). This can then be used to respond to them. Its used by  Macro software such as AutoHotKey, and by Keyloggers, that try to capture peoples passwords and such.
If you search for keylogger software, you will probably find some simple examples of use.